# PROC SQL Query Involving Two Datasets

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have two datasets that are both describing a player's time in two distinct football leagues during different time periods. There are times when players move from one league to another. I would like to output a dataset that consists of the observations for league 1 (dataset 1) where the players have played in both leagues at some point and the end date of a player's time with league 1 (dataset 1) is before the start time of this same player in league 2 (dataset 2).
Here is a description of the datasets:

Dataset 1 (League 1):

```
Player        Start_Date End_Date
Mark Jones    09/19/2019 09/18/2021 
Phil Lewis    09/07/2019 09/06/2020
Rena Williams 10/15/2018 10/15/2021
Roger Phelps  04/03/2016 05/15/2018
Trevor Knight 06/26/2017 04/20/2020
.             .          .
.             .          .
.             .          .
```

Dataset 2 (League 2):

```
Player             Start_Date End_Date
Rhonda Mars        07/28/2017 06/05/2021
Jack Hines         01/02/2019 10/10/2021
Mark Jones         05/07/2015 09/18/2019
Roger Phelps       05/20/2018 10/10/2021
William Henderson  05/07/2017 03/28/2021
.                  .          .
.                  .          .
.                  .          .
```

An example of the output desried:

```
Player       Start_Date End_Date    Transferred
Mark Jones    09/19/2019 09/18/2021 
Phil Lewis    09/07/2019 09/06/2020
Rena Williams 10/15/2018 10/15/2021
Roger Phelps  04/03/2016 05/15/2018 X
Trevor Knight 06/26/2017 04/20/2020
```

Here is a sample code I've written, which just gives produces an indicator column to distinguish if a player has played in both leagues:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE Shared_Players AS SELECT DISTINCT *,
   CASE
      WHEN Player IN (SELECT DISTINCT Player FROM League2) THEN "X" ELSE " " END AS Transferred
   FROM League1;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Have you tried to join the two tables ? For instance on name? (Better on player ID). If that is possible you can compare any date of the two sets.

Comment: @theking2 Do you mean something like this?
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE Dummy AS
SELECT * FROM League1 as x LEFT JOIN League2 as y
ON x.End_Date < y.Start_Date;
QUIT;

Comment: Almost. In the ON x.name = y.name. In a where clause the date comparison. But that could go in the on as well, depending on what indexes where defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
proc sql;
  create table onetwo as
  select one.* 
  , case when two.start_date > one.end_date then 'X' else ' ' end as xfer_1_to_2
  from one left join two on one.player = two.player
  ;
```